# 403 forbidden error while accessing the url having parameters like url?param=http://someurl.com/

Tags: url, https, server, webserver, aws-cloud9

I am facing the issue while accessing the below url in browser.

https://bootstrap.mytechlogy.com/?param=https&var=http

When the url contains parameters like https or http in querystring, it results 403 forbidden error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the line of code used to solve the above 403 forbidden issue.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]